# rails remove controller path from the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have the following loop in my view

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <%= link_to post do %>
           Some html
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above code will generate link as `localhost:3000/posts/sdfsdf-sdfsdf`

But I would like to have the link as `localhost:3000/sdfsdf-sdfsdf`

Here is my route

```
  resources :posts, except: [:show]

  scope '/' do
    match ':id', to: 'posts#show', via: :get
  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts, path: "" #-> domain.com/this-path-goes-to-posts-show
```

--

Also, make sure you put this at the *bottom* of your routes; as it will override any preceding routes. For example, `domain.com/users` will redirect to the `posts` path unless the `posts` path is defined at the bottom of the `routes.rb` file

--

**friendly_id**

In order to achieve a [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug)-based routing system (which works), you'll be best suited to using [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). This allows the `.find` method to look up `slug` as well as `id` for extended models:

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will allow you to use the following in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @post = Post.find params[:id] #-> this can be either ID or slug
   end
end
```

Comment: Nice - I am updating with info on slugs for you

Comment: Of course I am using friendly id but for link `resources :posts, path: ""`  this is the only way right?

Comment: Yep, unless you outputted the pages programmatically or something

Answer (score -1):

you need to tell routes what the name of the path gonna be.

in routes.rb you can do something like:

```
get '/:id', constraints: { the_id: /[a-z0-9]{6}\-[a-z0-9]{6}/ }, to: 'posts#show', as: :custom_name
```

after that when you run 'rake routes' you will see:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
custom_name GET    /:id(.:format)         post#show {:id=>/[a-z0-9]{6}\-[a-z0-9]{6}/}
```

Now that you have the prefix verb, you can use it to generate the link:
    <%= link_to 'Show', custom_name_path( post.id ) do %> 
    Some html
    <% end %>