# How to hide controller and action from URL in DEFAULT route

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I'm using MVC and having trouble figuring out how to hide the controller and action in the URL.
I have seen many things on how to hide the controller or the action but most are not for the default controller. 
My controller looks like this:

`routes.MapRoute("Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new{
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Index",
               id = UrlParameter.Optional
             });`

When you navigate to my site the URL looks like this:

www.mysite.com/Home/Index

I need it to hide the "Home" and "Index" so it looks like this:

www.mysite.com

I have the default route as the last route in the routeConfig file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your root URL. If so than use the following code in your routes.rb file.

```
root "home#index"
```

then you will get the www.mysite.com

However, there are many techniques to hide the controller and action from the url. Please have a look on this post [rails remove controller path from the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496657/rails-remove-controller-path-from-the-url)