# Rails: Remove Controller from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I've read a couple of posts, but I haven't found a clear solution.

I want to remove the controller from the URL. I'm getting this:

```
localhost:3000/pages/services
```

But I want this:

```
localhost:3000/services
```

This is my routes file right now:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#index'

  get 'pages/services'

  get 'pages/specials'

  get 'pages/events'

  get 'pages/about'

end
```

I suspect that I need to do something here, but I haven't been able to find a decent tutorial. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you try in this way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496657/rails-remove-controller-path-from-the-url

Comment: I saw that post, but I didn't really understand it. I'll put more time into comprehending, but I'm kind of looking for a reference on the concept. I looked through the rails docs, but didn't see something that resembled what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
match 'services' => "pages#services", :as => :services
```

You can specify a name for any route using the :as option.

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: How would I link this?

Comment: `<%= link_to "text", services_path %>`, you can run `rake routes > routing.log` and then `vi routing.log`. in the log, you can find path name.

Comment: Got it! I had it right, but it wasn't until I noticed that I didn't change all of the paths, that it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would just replace it with this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root '#index'
end
```

Comment: What about the other views?